# 404 after migrating Wordpress site to root folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, migration, http-status-code-404, root

I'm having a 404 when i want to migrate my website to the root folder.
For now i access site here: http://www.zeekray.com/wordpress/fr/

Here is what i've done: 
- I have changed the blog url to www.zeekray.com
- I 've copied the index.php and .htaccess files in the roots folder
- I've edited the index.php by adding . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'

But it didn't worked.

[www.zeekray.com](http://www.zeekray.com) redirects me to http://www.zeekray.com/wordpress/fr/

Comment: Can you show your .htaccess code?

Comment: `code`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: are you want to open your open page? can you confirm what error you are facing? I'm confused about 404 or redirection?

Comment: I try to access the site with www.zeekray.com but i'm being redirected to http://www.zeekray.com/wordpress/fr/. And at this url i'm having a 404 error.

Comment: I am being redirected to `wordpress/en`, which means that you have a plugin that handles your languages. I'm not very familiar with WordPress (in other words, I dislike it very much), and so I don't know the exact cause. Perhaps you have a GeoIP plugin installed? I would look there first.

Comment: I have a translation plugin installed which i assume knows where you're from. But i'm not sure if that's the problem. I'm gonna try disable it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I don't know why but seems like the custom permalinks were causing this. Now that i've set it to "Article name" it's working.